# http to https rewrite rules not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

I need to serve a form on the site using https. Let's say this is the form url:

http://www.mysite.com/cms/visit/residents/form

and requests need to go here:

https://www.mysite.com/cms/visit/residents/form

I'm on shared hosting, so I put this in the .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(cms/visit/residents/form.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine on our development server (Apache/Debian Squeeze), but when I put the .htaccess file live the rule doesn't work. Rewrite Engine is on and working fine because there are other rewrites and redirects already working in the .htaccess file. These other rules still work okay. I've asked the IT people here who host the site and they don't understand why the rule isn't working. I've tried countless variations to the above rules but can't get any to work on the live server. Here's another example I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^cms/visit/residents/form(.*) https://www.mysite.com/cms/visit/residents/form$1 [R=301,L]
```

I can rewrite from a page on the development server to the https url on the live server, so I don't think the target is a problem. All I can think of is that there's an interaction with the Apache configuration file on the live server, which contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.mysite.com
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteOptions inherit
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mysite.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
 RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=permanent,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.mysite.com
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteOptions inherit
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mysite.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
 RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=permanent,L]
 SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone got any ideas? I've been clearing the browser cache for each test, and checking the .htaccess file has uploaded correctly.

.htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php redirect.php index.htm
Options -Indexes +Includes +ExecCGI

ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.html 
ErrorDocument 401 /access-error.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(cms/visit/residents/form.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# To tidy up urls of pages run by live Drupal install (under /cms)
RewriteRule (^research/events/patronage.*) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/facilities/meeting-rooms/supervision-room-booking) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/facilities/meeting-rooms/function-room-booking) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^study/five-question-feedback-form) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/graduates/ballot-form) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/graduates/summer-rooms) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/undergrads/accommodation/survey) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/grads/accommodation/survey) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^graduate-accommodation) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^undergraduate-accommodation) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/easter-vacation) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^students/grads/accommodation/ballot.html) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^students/undergrads/accommodation/ballot.html) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/advent-booking) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/christmas-vacation) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/students/undergrads/summer-vacation) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^six-question-survey) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^conference-dining/feedback) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^intranet/meat-free) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^conference-dining/enquiry-form) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^study/undergraduate/open-days/booking-form) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^study/undergraduate/open-days/arts-form) cms/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (^study/undergraduate/open-days/sciences-form) cms/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule (^intranet/college.*) cms/$1 [L]

# For the Cognitive Studies course 2012-13
Redirect permanent /cognitive http://mysite.com/intranet/students/cognitive-skills.html
```

(Crazy amount of rewrites, I know, which I should condense into one rule!)

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` and keep this rule on TOP of all other rules just below `RewriteEngine on` line.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't work either. It just loads the http version.

Comment: OK in that case can you post your latest . htaccess in your question?

Comment: I've added it to the original post (can't work out how to do it here!)

Comment: .htaccess looks alright, what is the URI that you tried?

Comment: I've just thought: the form is actually at http:// www.mysite.com/cms/visit/residents/form. 
I simplified it above but I guess that was a bit dumb (sorry!) because maybe the 'cms' rewrites in the .htaccess were interfering, though I can't see any of a similar path. I've been trying http:// www.mysite.com/cms/visit/residents/form. 
(I've left a space in the urls after 'http://' here stop it getting stripped out by the forum software.)

Comment: Unrelated but you can use tilde character at start and end of a text to avoid HTML interpretation e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/cms/visit/residents/form`

Comment: Also tell me where did you place above .htaccess? Is it in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` or somewhere else?

Comment: It's at /site/htdocs/.htaccess i.e. at the top level of my root web directory. I assume that corresponds to $DOCUMENT_ROOT? Thanks for the tilde tip!